# Self-Referential Generic Type Constraints

Tags: c#, generics, types

I have a pool class:

`public class IPool<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : IPoolObject`

And an interface for objects that are put into pools:

`public interface IPoolObject`

I would like to inform the pool objects of which pool they are in. However, I don't quite know how to express this method. For example:

```
public interface IPoolObject{
  public void SetPool(IPool<IPoolObject> pool);
```

This doesn't work, because for a class `Foo : IPoolObject`, an `IPool<Foo>` can't be boxed into `IPool<IPoolObject>` (I think?)

What I want is to express the fact that it's receiving a generically-typed `IPool` that refers to its own type. But I don't think this is possible.

I do recall there being some weird patterns for generics in C# where you end up doing Foo : IPoolObject<Foo> or something in order to get generics to play nice. But I'm not sure if that's what the solution is here, looking for some guidance.

Comment: Prepend only interface names with an upper case `I`. Not classes. Can you show more about Pools and Pool objects? Why does the pool have to be generic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this was possible and `Bar` was a `IPoolObject`, you could write:

*(to comply with the C# naming conventions I renamed the pool class to `Pool<T>`)*

```cs
Pool<IPoolObject> pool = new Pool<Foo>();
pool.Add(Bar);
```

Therefore, these two types are not assignment compatible.

---

We must make the pool type more specific. To do this we must use this [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), as it is often called. It is curious but not forbidden or even harmful as [Eric Lippert explains here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/curiouser-and-curiouser).

```cs
public interface IPoolObject<T> where T : IPoolObject<T>
{
    public void SetPool(Pool<T> pool);
}
```

The pool class then declared like this (example):

```cs
public class Pool<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : IPoolObject<T>
{
    private HashSet<T> _pool = new HashSet<T>();

    public void Add(T poolObject)
    {
        _pool.Add(poolObject);
    }
}
```

`Foo` can then be implemented like this:

```cs
public class Foo : IPoolObject<Foo>
{
    private Pool<Foo> Pool { get; set; }

    public void SetPool(Pool<Foo> pool)
    {
        pool.Add(this);
        Pool = pool;
    }
}
```

The code above and this test are now compilable:

```cs
var fooPool = new Pool<Foo>();
var foo = new Foo();
foo.SetPool(fooPool);
```

Comment: Sometimes you wish there was just a `where T : this` constraint

Comment: @Charlieface, see [Proposal: 'this' generic type constraint to achieve a THISTYPE type #169](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/169).

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for this wonderful explanation! I really appreciate it and now I understand why I've seen that pattern occasionally (and marvelled at it).

Comment: @MikeCook: Exercise caution; the pattern works but (1) it makes the code hard to get your head around, and (2) it does not impose the "this" restriction that the comment above refers to; the restriction is weaker than you might think.  For example:

Comment: If we have `interface I<T> where T:I<T> {}` and `class C:I<C>{}` then `class D : C{}` also implements `I<C>` but `T` is still `C`, not `D`.